# Variant type without memory leak in Bison tokens

Tags: c++, bison, bisonc++

What is the **best non-memory-leaking variant type to use for texts in Bison** (for example `%token <std::string>`)?

I wanted to replace `char *` as the variant type for tokens with a more modern type (mainly to avoid memory leaks). I have tried with three types but still `char *` is by far the fastest:

```
char *                          2.35 (some metric)
std::string                     2.72 (some metric)
std::shared_ptr<std::string>    2.88 (some metric)
```

When I replaced `char *` with `std::string`, performance dropped. I knew it was because Bison's internal stack and the default operation `{$$ = $1}` in each statement were making redundant copies of the string, as `std::string` was designed to create a new copy and never share it (as opposed to the new `std::string_view`). I decided to try wrapping `std::string` into a light-weight copy operation class such as `std::shared_ptr`, but to my surprise, `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` resulted in **even lower performance**! Now I am completely lost.

I leave down here the files I have used. For the moment I neglected construction time of those three classes, but will only make `char *` faster compared to the other two.

After compiling them like this I ran it passing a big file and averaging `time` system execution time:

```
flex -o parser.cpp parser.l
bison -v -d --output=grammar.cpp grammar.y
g++ parser.cpp grammar.cpp
```

sharedText.hpp

```
#pragma once

// choose one option of "using SharedText = ..."

// option (3)
#include <memory>
#include <string>
using SharedText = std::shared_ptr<std::string>;

// option (2)
#include <string>
using SharedText = std::string;

// option (1)
using SharedText = char*;
```

yylex.hpp

```
# define YY_DECL        yy::grammar::symbol_type yylex()
YY_DECL;
```

grammar.y

```
%{
#include "sharedText.hpp"
%}

%require "3.8.2"
%language "c++"
%define api.parser.class {grammar}
%define api.value.type  variant
%define api.token.constructor

%code
{
#include "yylex.hpp"
}

%token <SharedText> SYMBOL NUMBER

%start start

%%
start
    : symbol_or_number
    | symbol_or_number start
    ;

symbol_or_number
    : SYMBOL
    | NUMBER
    ;

%%

namespace yy
{
void grammar::error(const std::string& description)
{
}
}

extern FILE *yyin;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    yy::grammar parse;
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    parse();

    return 0;
}
```

parser.l

```
%{
#include "sharedText.hpp"
#include "grammar.hpp"
#include "yylex.hpp"
%}

%option noyywrap

%%

<INITIAL>
{
[A-Za-z]+       { return yy::grammar::token::yytokentype::SYMBOL; }
[0-9]+          { return yy::grammar::token::yytokentype::NUMBER; }

"\n"            { ++yylineno; }
[ ]+            ;
.               ;
}
%%
```

Comment: If the string is never meant to change you can pass a `std::shared_ptr<const std::string>` around. Note that `shared_ptr`'s internals are thread safe, so the copy isn't as light as it may first seem.

Comment: I don't see any optimization flags in your build command. Measuring the performance of unoptimized code is generally meaningless. Try optimization flags like -O2 and -O3 and see what results you get.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux With `-O3` the results are both `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` 2.52, `char *` 2.57 and `std::string` is 2.70. Perhaps this test is not anymore representative of what is happening in my application, in which I can measure a clear performance drop (x10 slower).

Comment: If you copy a lot of small strings around, it is possible that they employ the Short String Optimization resulting in no dynamic allocations. With `std::shared_ptr` it would require a dynamic allocation for each string, and synchronization whenever the string pointer is copied which could further harm performance in a threaded solution.